# Did Kakashi eventually surpass Itachi, Jiraiya, Tsunade, and Orochimaru?

Tags: naruto

In the Naruto manga, [Kakashi Hatake](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kakashi_Hatake) has been acknowledged by both [Jiraiya](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Jiraiya) and [Tsunade](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Tsunade) to be one of Konoha's most powerful shinobi. But Kakashi himself had confessed that [Orochimaru](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Orochimaru) was on a completely different level from him, who in turn openly acknowleged that [Itachi Uchiha](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Itachi_Uchiha) was more powerful than him. [Obito Uchiha](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Obito_Uchiha) was noted to be more powerful than any other Uchiha except [Madara Uchiha](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Madara_Uchiha), whom Kakashi defeated.

My question is, at the time when Kakashi defeated Obito, had he surpassed all of Tsunade, Jiraya, Orochimaru and Itachi? Is there any reference in the manga itself from which a definite answer can be given, either in the affirmative or in the negative?

---

**Note:-** Before posting any answer to the question please read most (if not all) of the answers that's already posted below.

Comment: Think rock paper scissors. Just because rock beats scissors, that doesn't mean rock also beats paper. Also, I doubt Obito would have won against Itachi.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: The Rock-Paper-Scissor is a game based on the rule that doesn't imply the conclusion of my analysis. So, in this case, this example don't apply. By the way, Obito could easily defeat Itachi. As an example, note that Itachi's Amaterasu had no effect on him during his first meeting with Sasuke.

Comment: Obito had to use Izanagi (sacrificing an eye) to negate Amaterasu, there's no other explanation for how he did it. He can do it a maximum of two times, and he'd hesitate to use it with his Mangekyo eye.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: He didn't sacrifice his eye, at least during their first meeting with Sasuke.

Comment: In order to survive the surprise Amaterasu, he had to use Izanagi and sacrifice the eye that was behind the mask. He later replaced with with another eye from his stash (we saw he has tons), and then sacrificed another one against Konan.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: Even then, don't forget that he is a Mangekyo Sharingan user and the Ten-Tails Jinchuriki and so I think that Itachi would have been weaker than him.

Comment: Kakashi was nowhere near beating Obito in his Jinchuuriki form. [Let's continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-)

Comment: Am not sure about Tsunade, but Itachi, Jiraiya and Orochimaru definitely not. Itachi is on a totally different league and a true heir of Sharingan. Even obito was considering Itachi as an extremely dangerous threat to him. Then about Jiraiya, Itachi himself has admitted that even if he teams up with Kisame, still they would lose to Jiraiya. Then finally, Orochimaru. No one knows how many lives he has. He evolves from all the curse marks. Also he was on par with jiraiya even without his hands using seals.

Comment: Wait obito is powerful than itachi uchiha? Where was it ever mentioned?

Comment: @Madara is right. Also kishimoto said in a forum that itachi was the most smartest (strongest was it?) Uchiha he created. I wish I had the source to post now to back this argument. But if any of you had read that post... back me up here.

Comment: The only time I can think of Kakashi beating Obito (when he was strong) would be when Obito purposefully lost to him in order to further his plan, by getting the cursed seal removed from his heart.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha, Obito didn't use Izanagi to repel Amaterasu. He simply use Kamui to teleport the black fire Amaterasu to other dimension, and make himself untouchable by the black fire. Just exactly like Kakashi did to Deidara C4 bomb.

Comment: @SeasonalShot Itachi himself said that the fake Madara (aka. Obito) is more powerful than him & he can't defeat him when Obito first came to Konoha to steal Kurama.

Comment: @user170039 Kakashi didn't beat Obito. Read the manga. Obito let Kakashi chidori to destroy his heart because his heart is curse-sealed by Madara.

Answer (score 9):

**Taijutsu**

Jiraiya got the Frog Kumite, Tsunade has brutal strength, so it is clear here that in terms of Taijutsu, Kakashi is not as strong as those two. As for Orochimaru and Itachi, they don't use taijutsu much so it can be said that Kakashi could be on the same level or better.

**Ninjutsu**

Kakashi is the renowned Copy Ninja, the one who has copied over 1.000 jutsus. In term of Jutsu knowledge, it can be said he is on par with Orochimaru if not greater. Tsunade is not that great in ninjutsu other that ninjutsu for healing purposes. Jiraiya has great ninjutsus but if we talk about the jutsu element, Kakashi can perform 4 basic elements (Katon: Goukaku, Suiton: Suiryuudan, Doton: Doryuuheki, Raiton: Raikiri). He was also able to learn Rasengan, which was rated as an A rank jutsu. Meaning that it is very hard to learn. Itachi, being an Uchiha, would be able to copy jutsu the same way Kakashi did. So they can be said on the same level. However, it is not known whether Itachi can use 4 elements like Kakashi did. Itachi for sure can use fire jutsus as demonstrated during his fight against Sasuke. Kakashi learned to use Susano'o after Obito transferred his remaining chakra to him upon his death. So here, Kakashi can be said has surpassed the other 4 in this.

**Chakra**

Kakashi is very well known as having a low reserves of chakra. He commented that Naruto has about 4 times of his. And considering that Naruto-Sasuke-Sakura was like the new Sannin of Konoha, it can be said that Jiraiya has about the same or greater level of chakra than Naruto. Orochimaru as we know is a chakra monster, same with Tsunade. Itachi is pretty much on the same level as Kakashi in term of chakra reserves, except that being an Uchiha, he gets less strain than Kakashi in using the Sharingan.

**Genjutsu**

Kakashi is better in Genjutsu than Jiraiya, except of course, when Jiraiya used the help of Fukasaku and his wife (the frog sennins) to cast sound genjutsu. He should be better than Tsunade and Orochimaru too since he has the Sharingan. He, however, is far weaker than Itachi.

Based on this, we can say that overall, Kakashi hasn't surpassed the other 4. He's just pretty much on the same level, or a bit under the other 4.

Comment: Why Kakashi is far weaker in Genjutsu than Itachi? Note that Itachi didn't consider to use any other Genjutsu other than Tsukuyomi which is one of the most powerful jutsu he posses.  Besides, Kakashi fought on a par with the Ten-Tails Jinchuriki Obito in terms of Genjutsu. Also when he gained Obito's Mangekyo Sharingan and his chakra powers, he was able to perform Susanoo which can be used to be shielded from any type of Genjutsu and so Itachi's Tsukuyomi would then have no effect on him.

Comment: Well, maybe not far weaker, but still is weaker. Itachi is one of the best in using Genjutsu. He can even use his finger to cast genjutsu on Naruto. Kakashi was never seen doing the same or greater feat. When he use genjutsu, he has to use his eyes.

Comment: When Kakashi obtained Obito's power, he indeed became powerful than Itachi because then he could use Susanoo. My question specifically wants to know that did Kakashi surpass all of them when he was the Hokage? Also at the time when Itachi fought with Kakashi and defeated him, Kakashi seems to be unaware of his Mangekyo Sharingan which would (I think) keep him immune from Itachi's Tsukuyomi. Also note that a Genjutsu cast by a Mangekyo Sharingan can only be nullified by a Mangekyo Sharingan only, like the Rinnegan.

Comment: @user170039 If you ask when Kakashi became the Hokage, then there won't be any definite answer. His feats during his reign wasn't told. Also, just because he can use Susanoo, doesn't necessarily means he is more powerful than Itachi.

Comment: Of course not. But it at least mean that Itachi's Tsukuyomi would then have no effect on him as it did earlier (in fact I think that if Kakashi used Mangekyo Sharingan during their first battle, even then Tsukuyomi would have no effect on him). In fact I have described all these points in my answer. Please read it before commenting again.

Comment: The [naruto wikia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Wind_Release:_Rasengan) implies that Kakashi wasn't able to learn the Fuuton Rasengan. While the Rasengan itself is already an A-Rank justsu (according to it's wikia page) the inclusion of the element nature seems to be a step too big..

Comment: Additionally the [discussion page](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Talk:Kakashi_Hatake#Element_Icon_For_Kakashi) mentions that all wind-releases of Kakashi are not considered canon

Answer (score 3):

Kakashi can't spam his Kamui abilities so even if he could use it against pain, he probably only use it 1-2 times till he gets drained. Also, Kakashi is no where near the Sannins level. Unless you count Kakashi with the boosted power ups from Obito which I really don't give because he had the power for only 1-2 chapters ._. Itachi slays Kakashi, how much more proof you need to believe this ?! Orochimaru slays Kakashi... Kakashi fears the man as seen on many episodes.  Tsunade & Kakashi is the only reasonable fight seeing that tsunade is a medic ninja that has great strength & power. But even then Kakashi would have his hands full. Kamui spams is a bad reason for Kakashi to get the edge. Kakashi is my favorite character but this is too easy. & yes, Hokage Kakashi still loses. Hokage Kakashi is the weakest Kakashi since he has no sharingan & he probably can't use the jutsus he copied due to that. & you guys bring up the 1000 Jutsus he's copied yet we don't know what the jutsus are. Kakashi loses.

Answer (score 2):

In Naruto universe, Kakashi is a very famous shinobi and known far and wide. However, it would be wrong to say that he has surpassed everyone. It depends on the timing and circumstances.

- In the first bell test, Kakashi defeated Naruto, but in the second bell test, Naruto defeated Kakashi, so it all depends upon the circumstances.
- If we were to have a direct match between Jiraiya and Kakashi, Kakashi would be defeated. How? Well, Jiraiya faced pain in his full glory in Amegakure, i.e. the opponent's territory, while Kakashi could not defeat just one of Pain's Paths when Konoha was attacked.
- Next up is Tsunade. Jiraiya himself admitted that Tsunade once drew him near to death, and therefore she is more powerful than him. Thus, Kakashi can't defeat Tsunade either.
- Now comes up Orochimaru. During *Search for Tsunade* arc, we see a hell of a battle -- Tsunade and Jiraiya vs. Orochimaru, still Orochimaru was able to escape in the end. Thus, Kakashi can't defeat Orochimaru either.
- Now it's time for Itachi. In the very first days of Itachi's first premier in the series, Kakashi fought him and had to be admitted to the hospital for a very long time. Even in the Shippuden version, Itachi is just too powerful to be taken down.
- Then we have Obito. Well, I only watch the anime, and up until now, Kakashi has just been losing to Obito.

Those are the reasons why I say that Kakashi is not the most powerful one.

Comment: Your reasoning is almost perfect. But my question is not about what would happen if, say Jiraya fights with Kakashi. Even upto the Pain Arc, Jiraiya would surely win. But it should be noted that eventually Kakashi's chakra reserves improved. But the basic difference is that Jiraiya never fought any two of Pain's path simultaneously except very small times and that puts Jiraiya's situation in an advantage than that of Kakashi who fought both of them at the same time. It seems reasonable that Kakashi is constantly developing and hence when he defeated Obito, he had surpassed all of them.

Answer (score 2):

You must note that Kakashi did NOT defeat Obito. I say this because Obito knew about Madara's seal (chapter 675) and wanted to undo it to become the Ten-Tails Jinchuuriki. Also, he wasn't even trying to kill Kakashi. So he LET Kakashi STAB HIM IN THE CHEST. We all know that he could use his Rinnegan (because he used Edo Tensei) but he didn't use it in his fight with Kakashi. Kakashi couldn't even survive two Paths of Pain and Obito can use all of them and also Izanagi. Kakashi himself accepted that Orochimaru and Jiraiya (because Jiraiya fought all Six Paths of Pain BY HIMSELF) are better than him. I don't know about Tsunade, but Kakashi would be easily defeated by Jiraiya or Orochimaru.

Well, about Itachi, we all saw Itachi defeated Kakashi with his genjutsu in the original Naruto series when Itachi didn't even use Susanoo (his Susanoo had the Totsuka blade which could seal literally anything) or Amaterasu. Also, Kakashi, without Obito's Sharingan, is nothing in front of any of the above mentioned since Obito's eye allowed him to see his opponent's moves (he would've been defeated by Zabuza if he didn't have Obito's eye). Kakashi also agreed that the Chidori would've remained as an incomplete jutsu if he hadn't got Obito's Sharingan. It would also feel like you are cheating when only Kakashi's abilities are unknown and not Jiraiya's. One can escape from Kamui with good speed (as Minato did). Also, Kakashi exhausts almost all of his chakra if he uses Kamui twice and Jiraiya won't let him do that. Even if Kakashi uses Kamui on Jiraiya and Jiraiya got teleported into another dimension, he could easily summon himself back to Mount Myouboku by summoning one of the toads and then summon himself back to the real world. This would make Kakashi's Kamui useless and also would exhaust his chakra.

Comment: "Also, he wasn't even trying to kill Kakashi." - how can you say that? And regarding Jiraiya and Kakashi's comparison I have already said what I would say in my answer, so please go through it. "It would also feel like you are cheating when only Kakashi's abilities are unknown and not Jiraiya's" - I don't think that's true. Kakashi is known to have copied 1000 jutsus whereas no such feat is known to be attributed to Jiraiya.

Comment: The very fact that Obito wanted to get rid of Madara's Seal tells us that

Comment: Also, my meaning in saying that Obito was not trying to kill Kakashi is that he wasn't aiming to win the fight

Answer (score 2):

This question is not even that complicated a much as you guys make it seems...So let's break down and compare the skills of the four to Kakashi's skills...i be starting from the weakest to the strongest.

First, the weaker of the four would obviously be Tsunade...Taijutsu, well in this department Kakashi outclasses Tsunade by a long shot...Strength, Tsunade would make Kakashi look like childs, Offensive capabilities Kakashi takes this aswell, Ninjutsu, Kakashi has more than her and with both Mangekyou Sharingan kakashi would stomp her completely...So its pretty much Kakashi is stronger.

The second weakest I would say is Orochimaru...Orochimaru is on a different level when it comes to Taijutsu, Ninjutsu, and Genjutsu...Plus its impossible to killed the without sealing him...Remember his fight with the naruto's four tails...he got cut in two about a hundred (not literally) but he just shed his skin and he's good as knew...Sasuke tried to kill him, Itachi tried to kill him...crying out loud the entire Narutoverse tried to kill him...and he's still alive to date...he's impossible to kill...the dude has impure world resurrection, immortality to a huge extent, eight head serpent jutsu, a million and one jutsu, large chakra reserve.

Third weakest of the four would be Itachi...just like how Orochimaru wasnt debatable this is the same...Itachi wins...Itachi has Izanami, Susanoo'o (Sword of Totsuka and  Yata Mirror), Amateratsu, Tsukuyoumi...so there is no chance of winning.

Last Jiraiya...I just got one word for you sage mode...the man can summon a million and one toad to fight along side him...he has sage mode...that sealing justsu that can seal away anything (the one he use to seal Itachi's black flames), he has a wide range of jutsu aswell.

So from my observation of reading every single manga and watching all anime episode (Cannon and filler)...i can completely say the Kakashi is stronger than Tsunade with or without both Mangekyou...However the other three is just out of his league, they all have jutsu's and abilities that makes him look like child's play

Answer (score 1):

After reading all the answers, I think I can now make my own conclusion about the question.

### Kakashi vs. Itachi

In the anime, Itachi is certainly one of the most powerful shinobi. It has been observed that Kakashi was defeated by Itachi by the Tsukuyomi. This is one of the strongest jutsu that he could use. But as has been remarked earlier, Sharingan user can't protect himself from a Genjutsu cast by Mangekyo Sharingan. To remain immune, the opponent should at least use Mangekyo Sharingan (other than the method that Jiraiya said to Naruto, which applies mostly to the people with an immense amount of Chakra). Kakashi was seemingly unaware of his Mangekyo Sharingan at the time he fought Itachi,  so he failed to defeat Itachi.

It should also be noted that the Amaterasu would have no effect on Kakashi, because he could simply warp away the flame or move into the Kamui dimension. As for the Tsukuyomi, Kakashi's Susanoo would perfectly counter it.

Besides, as [**Sakurai Tomoki** noted in his answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/14966/), Kakashi can perform all 5 basic elements, which is a feat Itachi is not known to have. In this aspect, Kakashi is also ahead of Itachi. Itachi also noted that fighting Kakashi alone was dangerous with a high chance of injuries.

### Kakashi vs. Jiraya

While comparing between Jiraiya and Kakashi, it should be noted that in the anime, Kakashi was in a developing stage, meaning that his power was increasing whereas Jiraiya's power showed no notable development.

In terms of Taijutsu, Kakashi is surely ahead of Jiraiya, in contrary to [**Sakurai Tomoki**'s answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/14966/). Let me quote the relevant paragraphs from [Jiraiya](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Jiraiya#Taijutsu)'s article on Naruto Wiki:

> While not being his preferred combat method, Jiraiya was still very proficient with taijutsu, capable of stopping some of the individual dogs that split from the Giant Multi-Headed Dog just using his legs. His natural strength, while nowhere close to his team-mate Tsunade, was very impressive. In the anime, there is one such occasion where this is shown, when Jiraiya intervened in a fight between a young Gamabunta (who was still bigger than himself) and an unknown snake of equal size where Jiraiya grabbed and tossed the snake a great distance away with ease. Also in the anime, Jiraiya, as a child, was able to lift a large boulder several times his size. Jiraiya has showcased a high level of durability over the course of his life; taking a direct kick to the face from Might Guy, as well as surviving a direct blow from Nagato's Giant Ox, which ploughed him through several steel pipes, without getting injured. Even at the brink of death he still managed to figure out Pain's secret and engrave it on Fukasaku's back, so he could deliver the intel to Konoha.

This is all about Jiraiya. Now for [Kakashi](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kakashi_Hatake#Taijutsu):

> Kakashi is very adept in taijutsu. In the anime, as a child, he was skilled enough to hold his own against his sensei, Minato Namikaze, in his bell test, managing to touch one of the bells during the test. As an adult, his skills improved considerably, able to easily defeat hundreds of enemies using well-coordinated attack patterns to handle the multiple enemy strikes. Kakashi can also fight on par with Might Guy, a taijutsu master, ever since childhood. Likewise, from his various challenges against and mission with Guy, Kakashi has copied and developed considerable skill in his friend's Strong Fist-style and several of its techniques, enough to train others in its usage. He is also noted to have impressive speed; able to intercept an opponent faster than unfocused eyes could follow even from a distance.His speed allows him to effectively catch his opponents off-guard to quickly strike them down and easily evade attacks. Even against highly experienced assassins, Kakashi can silently sneak-up on them, making him prime to strike. His speed increased considerably in Part II; before the timeskip he had difficulty keeping up with Itachi Uchiha, but he out-manoeuvred him after the timeskip. Kakashi has also shown remarkable reflexes, able to instantly react and effectively manoeuvre out of surreal danger.
>
> Kakashi's speed is further seen during the Fourth Shinobi World War, able to enough to outmanoeuvre a Version 2 jinchūriki despite its enhanced and multiple fields of vision, and even keep pace with Might Guy using six of the Eight Gates. Kakashi was even able to blitz, and nearly sever Kaguya Ōtsutsuki's arm in one move, despite having her multiple dōjutsu active. Likewise, his hand seal prowess is very great, able to perform them at highly difficult speeds to follow. He can also open at least one of the Eight Gates, a feat that very few shinobi can achieve and, in the anime, utilise advanced techniques derived from it while showing no signs of fatigue afterwards. His raw strength is also noticeably high, able to clash with a physically strong opponent like Zabuza Momochi, who was wielding the rather heavy Kubikiribōchō, simultaneously throw Naruto and Sasuke a large distance, snap one of Nagato's chakra receivers with his bare hand, and later easily wield Kubikiribōchō himself with a single hand for extended periods of time. He's shown a rather impressive level of durability and endurance, able to survive Nagato's building busting Shinra Tensei from upclose with minimum damage and continue fighting afterwards.

[**user3275697** remarked](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/14942) that Jiraiya fought Pain in his full glory, while Kakashi wasn't able to defeat even one Path of Pain. True. But the difference in Jiraiya and Kakashi's situation is that Jiraiya fought with the Paths with Gamaken and defeated them in his Sage Mode, while Kakashi fought the two Paths of Pain without even using his Mangekyo Sharingan. Therefore, no conclusion can be drawn from this fact.

Except for Jiraiya's Genjutsu, it should be noted that Kakashi has the ability to encounter all of Jiraiya's attack. For example, he can easily warp away Jiraiya's Rasengan, which he used in his battle against Pain.

Besides, I personally think that if Kakashi were to fight with the Paths of Pain whom Jiraiya fought against, he would be at an advantage because of his warping ability. He could simply warp the summoned animals into Kamui dimension, while Jiraiya could not.

Also, Kakashi is certainly ahead of Jiraiya in terms of Ninjutsu. ***He is said to copy about 1000 jutsus.***

### Kakashi vs. Orochimaru

It is really very hard to compare them. However, Kakashi has improved a lot since their first fight (note that he didn't know how to use the Mangekyo Sharingan at the time of their first fight) and nothing can be said with certainty. However, one thing that is worthy (perhaps) to note is that in the statistics between Orochimaru and Kakashi, [Orochimaru](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Orochimaru#Stats) stands at 35, while [Kakashi](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kakashi#Stats) is at 34.5

### Kakashi vs. Tsunade

In this case, I think that Kakashi can easily surpass Tsunade in every other cases, except for reserves of chakra. But nothing authentic can be concluded, so I go with [**user3275697**'s answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/14942).

Answer (score 1):

Simple analysis (from Madara):

> Think rock paper scissors. Just because rock beats scissors, that doesn't mean rock also beats paper. Also, I doubt Obito would have won against Itachi.

Now to answer the first question: 
**Kakashi defeated Obito. Had he surpassed all of Tsunade, Jiraya, Orochimaru and Itachi?**

**Partially no.** With regards to strength (chakra and ninjutsu), defeating someone with such strength like Obito doesn't mean he surpasses the others that he already defeated. This scenario always happens in real life.

**Partially yes.** What made Kakashi special is his tactics. He is known to be a genius because of his strategies in combat. Given his limited reserve of chakra, he can analyze fully the situation, come up with a possible solution, and utilize all the resources he has (chakra, techniques, etc) and maximize them all to execute it. Winning a battle is always his goal. Focus is the key.

**Is there any reference in the manga itself from which a definite answer can be given, either in the affirmative or in the negative?**

This would be tricky. I can cite all the battles of Kakashi in manga/anime, but that requires a lot of space. Just watching/reading all his battles, you can tell that he is indeed a genius because he always thinks and analyzes everything before he makes a move.

Just an example: when Kakashi and Guy rescue Naruto against Obito, they were patiently waiting for Obito to materialize. That alone can tell how skilled Kakashi is. He used the element of surprise.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, Kakashi did surpass them all, **momentarily** that is. I don't see Jiraiya, Orochimaru and Tsunade taking on Kakashi with his double Mangekyō Sharingan (Complete Body Susanoo, plus both variants of Kamui).

Itachi, on the other hand, just might have a chance against him. Since Itachi's Susanoo is equipped with Totsuka Blade and Yata Mirror, which was stated to be **essentially invincible** by Zetsu, he might have a chance against Kakashi's Susanoo.

Double Mangekyō Sharingan Kakashi surpassed the Legendary Sannin and Itachi possibly, but then again, he lost his Sharingan power ups.

### Conclusion

Yes, he did surpass them when he got the Double Mangekyō Sharingan boost. However, the "Hokage Kakashi" is way behind Jiraiya, Orochimaru and Itachi. He still might be able to win against Tsunade.

Comment: Jiraiya, Orochimaru and Itachi even didn't take the single-mangekyo-Kakashi. As I said in my answer, I think that Kakashi's first defeat from Itachi was due his not using the mangekyo sharingan because a normal sharingan can't dispel the genjutsu cast by an mangeykyo sharingan. Also don't forget his fight with Sasuke.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is yes!! an those are my reasons: kakshi vs tsunade: kakahi can do better ninjutsu with his 2 eyes sharingan he can do perfect form susano and kamui kakashi can also do better genjustsu than her with his sharingan and finaly taijutsu tsunade is phisiqly stronger than kakashi but much slower so she wont be able to hurt him and even if she will he can use the kamui to disappear so kakashi won this fight: kakashi vs jiriya: kakashi can do better ninjutsu than jiraiya and im not sure about taujutsu or genjutsu but kakashi is so strong with his susano that i cant realy see him losing to jiraiya and i also cant see jiraiya realy doing anithing against kakashi so kakashi won this fight: kakashi vs orochimaru :  so orochimaru basicly is a very tough oponent to everione but his taijutsu ang genjutsu are much weacker than kakashis and even his ninjutsu  is not the atckung type like kakashi orochimaru do ninjutsu that can hurt you diefferntly like reanimation but if this two will face each other rendomaly kakashi will win for sure i know that in the early childhood and even in part one kakashi fear orochimaru but now with his power level and the 2 eyes sharingan he can destroy orochimaru: so kakashi won this fight: kakashi vs itachi: so i will begin i in the backround... in part one kakshi was defeated by his genjutsu that surpraisdhim but back then kakashi didnt have the mangekyo shrungan an definatly not 2 eyes mangekyo sharingan... itachi can do the uncomplete susano while kakashi can do the perfect for  and it even can fly itachi can do realy good genjutsu even better tahn kakashi but with the mangekyo  shruingan can see through his genjutsu just like sasuke didto him in thei big fight taht sasuke won and here is one of itachis weaknesses hes low stamina... and now moving to taijutsu itachi is pretty good in taijutsu but also kakasi but kakashi can do kamui and i know some pepole will say that kakashi can do the kamui more than 2-3 times but now  he can pretty much do it as much as he want becasu he has 2 eyes sharingan so i think if they both will clash and itachi will fight the same as he fought against sasuke or even better he will still lose to kakasi itachi and kakashi are both very smart but kakashi is stronger than itachi so kakshi won this fight: and those are the reasons why kakshi is stronger than orochimaru jiraiya tsunade and itachi

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fact for you. Itachi died when Kakashi was still evolving and getting better. Itachi was considered superior to all of the genjutsu users except madara of course. If Itachi was alive, he would have been stronger. If he would have taken shisui's eyes, his eternal mangekyou would have far surpassed anyone else's because shisui and itachi were considered to be on the same level. Itachi did not take his eyes by choice. And none of kakashi's attacks can go through yata mirror. And the totsuka blade seals susanoo. Which can be resurrected again but on casting the jutsu again. And people forget about yasaka magatama. One long range attack that cannot be blocked and is considered as strong as the tailed beast chakra infused rasen shuriken. Now imagine amaterasu around the yasaka magatama. And please, never forget izanami. Sage mode counters genjustsu. Yet kabuto being the perfect sage couldnt escape izanami. Who knows what more he would have learned if he was alive. So I believe Kakashi was far from competing against Itachi. Remember Orochimaru didnt even dare fight Itachi. He was willing to fight tsunade and jirayia at the same time but not Itachi. The answer is clear.

Comment: You forgot to mention Yakumo and Kurenai. Kurenai was considered on the same level in terms of Genjutsu as Itachi.

Answer (score 0):

I feel there are way too many misconceptions on this topic. I don't understand where half these answers are coming from, as a naruto fan for over 11 years now.

**Tsunade:**

I saw someone speak of Tsunade's strong taijutsu. Tsunade is a horribly weak fighter. The reason she's can punch so hard is because of her chakra control, which she fully explained to Sakura in the training flashbacks. Mind you, that she was *losing to Kabuto*. It was often stated that Kabuto was *"Just on Kakashi's level"*. Meanwhile, Kabuto was one of the strongest people in the series. Don't forget that Tsunade is a medic and not a fighter. She's exceptional as a medic, not as a fighter. As a fighter she's just your everyday jounin level.

**Jiraiya:**
I saw someone answer about his taijutsu as well, stating it's so strong because of his Frog Kimute. Well, he can only use that in sage mode. Either way, I do believe Jiraiya was the strongest of the sannin and would indeed quite easily beat Kakashi. There is simply no doubt about this... or is there? The fact is that these people know each other well. If Jiraiya wouldn't know about Kakashi's sharingan, specifically his "I'm gonna shoot you into another dimension!" trick, He'd probably lose by surprise. Kakashi is an assassin type ninja and would almost always win a fight when it came to trickery.

**Orochimaru:**

I'm quite sure Orochimaru would win, simply because he's pretty much immortal. He has a lot of very dirty tricks and Kakashi wouldn't have the chakra/stamina to keep up the fight. Without that, Kakashi would probably win, though.

**Obito:**

Obito would probably kick Kakashi's ass, but he would also kick the asses of the Sannin. People like Orochimaru posed no threat to him at all. Obito is super OP. besides this, his Sharingan is way stronger than Kakashi's.

**Itachi:**

Kakashi would simply lose to Itachi. Itachi is possibly the strongest character to have ever existed. A lot of people tend to say "Aside from Obito/Madara", but I disagree. Itachi was the most genius ninja ever known to anyone, as far as we know. All we have seen from Itachi was a display of power while he was dying. We have, not once, seen Itachi go full power. His Susanoo's was so strong for a reason, though. Although Madara is sickeningly OP, I wouldn't be so sure that Obito is stronger than Itachi, let alone Kakashi.

**Kakashi himself:**

It should be noted that Kakashi's power hasn't been extremely stable throughout the series. Kakashi is known for having a laughably small chakra pool. Pretty much every genin we've seen has had a bigger chakra pool than Kakashi, especially when he uses his Sharingan.
Having said that, Kakashi is known for being a tactical genius. He's an assassin-type ninja, and would kill nearly anyone if he, for once, was the ambusher. He analyses every situation perfectly and always finds a great plan to deal with it.
That being said, absurdly OP people like orochimaru and Itachi wouldn't be bothered by it, as orochimaru immortal and Itachi is just as much a genius as Kakashi is, if not even more so. Basically, Kakashi would win almost any fight if he was the one to initiate it and his opponent would actually die from having their hearts deleted... :P

-- my final conlusion is: No, Kakashi did not surpass them in the sense of all-round power, but he did surpass them in a strategical sense. Basically, you'd want Kakashi as your team-leader, where as Jiraiya should be the one he's bossing around. Kakashi is basically the boogeyman. He's most dangerous when you don't see him :)

Comment: In he second fight between "Itachi" and Kakashi, I think that Kakashi could also easily defeat "Itachi" once he grabbed him (just make another shadow clone and use chidori) - Naruto wasn't needed at all.

Comment: @user170039 I have to agree, but also disagree. In the first place, Itachi could just use his infinite tsukyomi on Kakashi again if he felt like it. As is stated in the manga: If you find yourself alone against Itachi's sharingan, RUN. BUT, if you ignore this for a second, then yes. Kakashi could win. But it is also stated that the fake Itachi is only 20% as strong as the real one, so... there's that, yeah?

Comment: Kakashi was aware that Itachi could just use his tsukuyomi (Itachi can't use infinite tsukuyomi)  on Kakashi again and due to this he let the shadow clone take his place. In my opinion, even though it was real Itachi, Kakashi could defeat him all alone.

Comment: Regarding Jiraiya, what makes you say that Jiraiya was the strongest of the Sannins?

Comment: @user170039 I can't really agree with that. Kakashi has an extremely small chakra pool so using shadow clones is a very bad idea for him. He's an assassin type and has little endurance. I think Jiraiya is the strongest, simply because he was "proven to be". It has been well established that Orochimaru was stronger than Tsunade. Now, Orochimaru was afraid of Itachi and Pain. However, Jiraiya wasn't. Jiraiya pretty much only lost to Pain because of the surprises, but he was an extremely strong ninja. However, I don't remember this all too wel anymore, sorry :')

Comment: Jiraiya hasn't proven himself to be stronger than Orochimaru. The only time they fought face to face was the time when both of them was not at their best from which no conclusion can be drawn. Regarding Pain, I would rather say that Jiraiya didn't fight the same paths that either Kakashi or Orochimaru fought. If Jiraiya did and defeated them (a feat neither Kakashi nor Orochimaru could accomplish) then probably we could make some definite conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

You're all wrong. Kakashi definitely surpassed the sannin, maybe not jiraiya or on the same part as jiraiya. But itachi, hell no. With his mastery in taijutsu, kenjutsu, dojutsu, genjutsu, and ninjutsu, kakashi even with a full body Susanoo would never stand a chance. Like zetsu said, with itachis yata mirror and totsuka blade, he's basically invincible.

He was a genius with kage level thinking as a child as stated in the Manga and anime. Kakashi didn't have kage level thinking until he was kage.

Kishimoto, the creator himself said itachi was the strongest of all naruto characters and that he had to give him the illness to kill him off because itachi would have wiped the floor with madara and then there'd be no story. I'd go so far to say itachi could quite possible stand a chance against sasuke in his prime as an adult  (possibly)

But no way kakashi surpassed Itachi.

Itachi>Madara>Obito=Kakashi>jiraiya>orichimaru>tsunami

Itachu wipes floor with every single person above. Hands down. His totsuka blade and yata mirror alone. Not to mention his mastery of every type of juts  (ninja, Gen, ken, do, Tai, etc.

So no, itachI still beats kakashi in prime.

Comment: Can you show us the official statement of Kishimoto in which he says that "Itachi was the strongest of all Naruto characters..."?

Comment: Madara>Hashirama>Obito>Nagato>Jiraiya>Itachi>Orochimaru>Kakashi>Tsunade

Answer (score 0):

LOOOOOL. You people are insane...need I remind anyone how Itachi was the only Uchiha (in a time where maaaaany Uchiha still existed) that sensed Tobi/Madara and basically told him, "I'll give you a chance to bounce, or else..." 
Kakashi is defo a powerhouse, but nothing near Itachi. There HASN'T been anyone to defeat Itachi that we know of. The guy was a genius to the end, only perishing to a gay illness given to him to further the story line and the only way someone so OP could ever be defeated. Itachi never lost his cool, he never seemed cornered, it's like EVERYTHING he did was perfectly calculated. There is no way in hell Kakashi could defeat Itachi. Not with one sharingan, not with two...
How many times have we seen Kakashi defeated? How about cornered? Many...
I cannot believe anyone is seriously considering Kakashi defeating Orochimaru. Orochimaru is the epitome of a cockroach; the son of a bitch is indestructable. He has been researching his whole life prohibited jutsus...ugh, I honestly don't want to write all the things he can do, not to mention the Tsunade-Jiraiya fight against him, where he wasn't even able to use HIS ARMS OR JUTSUS.
Come on people....Jiraiya? The guy is much wiser than Kakashi, who couldn't defeat one Pain while Jiraiya fought them all. The guy was a freaking old man and still was a powerhouse. He can tap into Sage mode and we all know that Sage mode is what the First used to counter Madara's sharingan...
Why count a boost in power given by a dying Obito that lasted a mere 2 chapters? If that's the case then why not make him fight against Itachi without an illness or Jiraiya in his prime? It's like people look for reasons to make Kakashi stronger than the rest, when he clearly isn't.
He can use all 5 styles...buuuuuhuuuuuu! He can use Kamui....buuuuuhuuuuu! Let's see how much kamui is useful when he uses it twice and finds himself with less than a third of his chakra.